# cd to a symlink, is the same to cd to original folder?

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, cd-command

I want to create a symbolic link just for convenience (I don't want a type a long path), so if I do something like:

```
ln -s /foo/bar/baz ~/baz
cd baz
```

All commands that I run while I'm in `~/baz` will run exactly the same way if I am in `/foo/bar/baz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost... The `cd` and `pwd` commands will behave as if you are in `~/baz` (although you can `cd` to subdirectories of `/foo/bar/baz` inside `~/baz`, when you `cd ..` you will be in `~`)

All other commands will behave as if you were in the real directory and all permissions will be preserved (of course - that's why we say symlinks have "dummy permissions").

This includes (potentially confusingly) commands with relative paths that extend outside the directory. With the exception of `cd`, which considers you to be in `~/baz`, you must make sure you use them as if you are in the real directory, not the symlink. For example if you wanted to `ls` the contents of `/foo/bar`, in `~/baz` you could do `ls ..` and if you wanted to symlink a file in `foo/bar` in `/foo/bar/baz`(let's call it `kitten`) then inside `~/baz` you could do `ln -s ../kitten kitten`

Comment: `pwd -L` will give your *logical* working directory (respecting symlinks).  `pwd -P` will give your *physical* working directory (ignoring symlinks).  To keep things confusing, the bash builtin `pwd` defaults to `pwd -L` while `/bin/pwd` on an ubuntu system defaults to `pwd -P`.   So it is true that `pwd` will behave as if you are in `~/baz` as long as you are using the bash builtin.  (Not sure about other shells).

Comment: `cd -P ..` will move take you to the Physical parent directory instead of popping one branch off the logical directory tree.