# What does the permission string lrwxrwxrwx mean?

Tags: permissions

When I `cd` to `/` and enter the command:

```
ls -ls
```

for some files/folders it gives output like:

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root   root         7 Jan 30  2018 bin -> usr/bin
```

So what actually is this `lrwxrwxrwx`?

Comment: @Kulfy I think the fact that OP provided `ls -l` in their question suggests they already know how to view permissions.  They're more interested in the meaning of the output in this particular case of symlinks. So I don't think that's an appropriate duplicate

Comment: @Serg [g_p's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/528433/301745) has the info OP is looking for, but I agree it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: @Serg The dup Q&A is generically orientated on meaning of permissions. If a question of `lwrxwrxwrx` (see `/vmlinuz`) like this is unique, would a question of `dwrxwrxwrx` (see `/tmp/`) be unique as well? If each combination of permissions is a unique question we can have untold number of what could be considered psuedo-dups. For example ***"What does permissions of `dr-xr-xr-x` for `/proc` directory mean"?***.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix While I agree the dup is general and should cover wide range, including this one, this question happens to talk about specific file type and the set of permissions `lrwxrwxrwx` is typical to all symlinks, which Zanna's answer covered very well in detail. If you feel like this should be covered in the linked dup, feel free to either post an answer or edit the existing ones there.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Then it opens the door to another potential dup ***"What is a symbolic link?"*** or ***"What does `l` mean in permissions***". As for me posting an answer on dup I respectfully decline on the grounds Zanna would do a much better job and would deserve the credit of porting her answer over there with any minor tweaking that might be required... In any respect I think there could be a generic Q&A on what the file control field means including symoblic links, hard links, (root, group, user) permissions, pipes, sockets and what not that can appear in the file control field.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  That's a slippery slope fallacy.  The purpose of the duplicates is to provide appropriate information, not cover everything, nor they are meant to prevent people from asking similar questions. I've already expressed my opinion - Zanna's post here does better job than what's covered in the link, and the questions differ somewhat. The rest may the community decide

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I agree on community deciding. Mods can step in and merge if need be. I DO like Zanna's answer :)

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Actually i thought the same what wjandrea mentioned but was still doubtful. So I just casted a vote and let the community decide about the fate of the question. Nonetheless, I've casted my reopen vote :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The leading `l` indicates that this file is a [symlink](https://askubuntu.com/tags/symbolic-link/info), in contrast to `-` which indicates a regular file, `d` which indicates a directory, and [other less common prefixes](https://askubuntu.com/tags/files/info).

A symlink is type of file which only contains a link to another file. Reading a symlink reads the real file. Writing to a symlink writes to the real file. `cd`ing to a symlink that is to a directory results in behaviour [almost identical](https://askubuntu.com/questions/817292/cd-to-a-symlink-is-the-same-to-cd-to-original-folder/817303#817303) to what would happen if you had `cd`'d into the real directory.

The [permission bits](https://askubuntu.com/tags/permissions/info) are displayed as `rwxrwxrwx`. All symlinks show these bits, but they are "dummy permissions". The actual (or effective) permissions of a symlink are the permissions of the real file it links to. You can get the real permissions (and file type) by running `stat` on the symlink, for example:

```
$ stat -Lc '%a %A' /initrd.img
644 -rw-r--r--
```

- `stat` read file metadata
- `-L` dereference (follow) symlinks
- `-c` select output according to specified string
- `%a` octal permissions
- `%A` "human readable" permissions

Comment: No need to use `readlink`, just use option `-L` to dereference symlinks. You can do `stat -L` or `ls -L`.

Comment: `ls` also has a `-L` option to follow the link.

Comment: @Barmar good point :)

Comment: `The actual permissions of a symlink are the permissions of the real file it links to. ` Um, not quite. This needs to be reworded. Symlinks are symlinks - you already mentioned they show dummy permissions that all symlinks show, and actual file is different from symlink.  Nonetheless, good and detailed answer. +1'ed already

Answer (score 2):

#### The ls -sl command

The Linux command `ls` = List of files in the directory you are in

The added switch `-sl` = print short list

The resulting this example part of the output: `lrwxrwxrwx`

In my shortest explanation would be: 
The first letter will usually be either: `l`, `d`, or `-`:

`l` = Link to another file

`d` = a directory

`-` = file

`r` = read permission - Read the file

`w` = write permission - Write or edit the file

`x` = execute permission He can execute the file

`-` = no permission

```
Number  Permission Type            `Symbol`
0         No Permission             `---`
1         Execute                   `--x`
2         Write                     `-w-`
3         Execute + Write           `-wx`
4         Read                      `r--`
5         Read + Execute            `r-x`
6         Read + Write              `rw-`
7         Read + Write + Execute    `rwx`
```

In Summary: 
The file type and access and Permissions the Ownership, and User; privileges such as Read and/or Write for each directory or file that is listed in the output.

a `l` for a link , `d` for a directory or `-` for a file and these are set by the Linux operating system. You can not manually change these letters (unless you change the file type of course). 
(ie... `lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root       1024 Feb 13 09:45 myfile3`)

Please refer to: http://earthen.tripod.com/linuxper.htm[Permissions (Setting up the modes)](http://earthen.tripod.com/linuxper.htm)

~ Samuel F Campbell